# c# windows mobile getdeviceid()

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

How can I get an ID unique to a particular device (Windows Mobile)?

I've tried `getdeviceid()`, but similar devices will return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe getting the MAC address?

Comment: Using the MAC address would indeed be the best way. You can take a look at this example, that should be supported in the compact-framework.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/network.aspx

Comment: In the example you gave no mac address, ip and got the name. getdeviceid () function allows the device number is the same number, but if the same model device. him that there were people trying to find the unique values of a function.